# r, cache, safety and *apply

Tags: r, caching, thread-safety, lapply

I would like to improve a R package of mine with caching for subfunctions without changing the results (only optimization).

i've seen that cache packages exist like **memoise**. It seems also be possible to simply store some calls with a closure inside the package, the simplest example would be like

```
multiplyby3_generator <- function() {
  save <- c(0,0)
  function(value) {
    if (value != save[1]) {
      save <<- c(value,3*value)
      warning("Recalculation !")
    }
    return(save[2])
  }
}
multiplyby3 <- multiplyby3_generator()
multiplyby3(3)
# [1] 9
# Warning message:
# In multiplyby3(3) : Recalculation !
multiplyby3(3)
# [1] 9
```

However, how can you make it safe and useful to use that kind of things inside a package ?

As far as I understand :

- If I did something like my example, I would have to forbid every kind of parallel computing on the mother function. Otherwise there would be a risk for the reference `save` to be changed between the `if (value != save[1])` and the `return(save[2])`. Can you forbid parallelization and would it be enough to make it safe ? Or is it another way to make it safe ?
- for a cache to be useful, one has to know how the *apply behave. The code `invisible(lapply(1:100,function(i) print(i)))` tends to show that the evaluation order of a lapply is the order of the list. Is that always the case ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, parallelization could be an issue. The environment would be copied to the workers but updates would not happen in the main R sessions. "order evaluation of a lapply is the order of the list. Is that always the case ?" Yes, it's a simple sequential loop.

Comment: @Roland thanks. If the environment is simply copied, then there's no danger i guess ? I want to make it never wrong. Are the environments copied in each parallization paradigm that exists in R ? if the cache is simply copied at launch there's no danger

Comment: As I wrote, updates to the "saved" values would not exists in the main R session. That might be an issue or not, depending on the actual application.

Comment: Keep in mind that parallel operations are **never** safe when one thread or worker ever depends on another worker.  Where or how you cache results is almost a separate issue

Comment: Thanks @Carl Witthoft. The idea wasn't about using parallel computing myself but about making something legit enough to avoid problems no matter what the user does. As i understand, it's fine as long as my function results doesn't depend on the updates (which  don't intend to since it's only optimization, not results updating)